# PHP Codeigniter - where do you put actions?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, model-view-controller

I'm still quite new to programming but have been using PHP\CodeIgniter for a year or two.

I've been keeping my controllers really clean recently by putting all my data retrieve options in models, just loading and retrieving data in my controllers via the models and then passing this to views.

Now I also have script for example that pings some IP's and reports on the status, at the moment I have this "action" in a model, feeding the result back into a DB, then another model/method that pulls the results to parts of the application that need that information. I thought this was the cleanest way.

Yesterday I came across an article/discussion where people pointed out some code as "wrong" as the user was performing "actions" in a model rather than just retrieving data, which apparently is all models should do.

So my question is, to keep my code clean but adhering to best practice, where is the best location to keep my actions? Some actions can be 50-100 lines easy, so I don't want them clogging up my controllers.

I know there isn't a perfect answer as everyone does things different, I was just wondering how many years experience you have and what it is that you do?

Thanks
R

Answer (score 1):

I always use the logic when doing MVC...

I want FAT models and SKINNY controllers...  e.g the bulk of logic goes into the models for easy re-usability, controllers should be lean to make it easier to read/follow.

Just my 2 cents.. (or 2 pence)

Answer (score 0):

### Model - The "M" in "MVC"

The Model's job is to represent the problem domain, maintain state, and provide methods for accessing and mutating the state of the application. The Model layer is typically broken down into several different layers:

- **Service layer** - this layer provides cohesive, high-level logic for related parts of an application. This layer is invoked directly by the Controller and View helpers.
- **Data Access layer** - (ex. Data Gateway, Data Access Object) this layer provides access to the persistence layer. This layer is only ever invoked by Service objects. Objects in the data access layer do not know about each other.
- **Value Objects layer** - this layer provides simple, data-oriented representations of "leaf" nodes in your model hierarchy.

**Red Flags:** My Model architecture might be going bad if:

- The Model contains session logic.
- The Value Objects retain (ie. store) references to Service objects or Gateway objects.

If the above "red flag" conditions start to happen, then I probably have a Model layer that is breaking encapsulation. By letting the service layer refer to sessions, I am also creating a Model that is hard to test without having an entire application in place. Furthermore, having session references in the model makes the model incredibly hard to reuse across different controllers (as per my web/API split mentioned earlier).

> Read this [PDF](https://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps183/Spring10/lectures/codeigniter.pdf)

---

### View - The "V" in "MVC"

The View's job is to translate data into a visual rendering for response to the Client (ie. web browser or other consumer). The data will be supplied primarily by the Controller; however, the View may also have a helper that can retrieve data that is associated with the rendering and not necessarily with the current request (ex. aside data, footer data).

**Red Flags:** My View architecture might be going bad if:

- The View contains business logic.
- The View contains session logic.

If the above "red flag" conditions start to happen, then I probably have a View layer that is doing too much. Business logic should be factored out into a Service object. And, session references should probably be factored out into a Helper object or a Controller. This will make the Views easier to build and to test since they rely solely on data and not on an entire application being in place.

> NOTE: *View rendering is something that I am still fuzzy on. My current approach uses a CFM-only approach to rendering; as such, integrating Components into a view rendering lifecycle is still something that I need to think about.*

---

### Controller - The "C" in "MVC"

The Controller's job is to translate incoming requests into outgoing responses. In order to do this, the controller must take request data and pass it into the Service layer. The service layer then returns data that the Controller injects into a View for rendering. This view might be HTML for a standard web request; or, it might be something like JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) for a RESTful API request.

**Red Flags:** My Controller architecture might be going bad if:

- The Controller makes too many requests to the Service layer.
- The Controller makes a number of requests to the Service layer that don't return data.
- The Controller makes requests to the Service layer without passing in arguments.

If the above "red flag" conditions start to happen, then I probably have a Controller layer that is doing too much. I should probably factor the logic out into a more cohesive Service layer that can be invoked by the Controller. Furthermore, if the Controller is making requests to the Service layer without passing in arguments, then I may have a Service layer that is breaking encapsulation (ex. referring to the Session, CGI, FORM, or URL scopes).

Answer (score 0):

Your thoughts are not completely wrong.

Anyway taking controllers small is a pretty awesome practice imho. This is against building "fat" controllers.
But I think that in your case you have to decouple the "business logic" in a separate class (Service Layer) and use it in your controller. 
Just of "separation of concerns". Just build your domain logic, "framework agnostic", outside your controllers.

The controller has not the responsibility of business logic or some other stuff in addition to forward the model's data to the view, in the opposite case you're violating the Single Responsibility Principle.

I found a good starting point in the ADR pattern by Paul M Jones here http://pmjones.io/adr/ and shows you how to decouple your business domain logic from your framework.

I also suggest you going into [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) to learn about more flexible application architecture

Comment: thanks very much. I'll give the ADR article a read now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep business logic in Models and keep Controllers smaller if possible by making abstract functions in controllers for repetitive tasks.

Use ORM to maintain best practices and readable code. Here are the ones I use

1. [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)
2. [DataMapper](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/)